# How do I count the number of occurrences of a string in a Dataframe field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like so:

```
0                           Physician (Family Practice)   99
1                 Transportation Security Officer (TSO)   94
2                                    Physical Therapist   94
3                              Physician (Psychiatrist)   81
```

I want to count / group the dataframe such that all the rows with the 'Physician' word in it (a partial match) will be summed together, so I get the following:

```
0                                             Physician   180
1                 Transportation Security Officer (TSO)   94
2                                    Physical Therapist   94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way (assuming the columns are named "Job" and "Num"):

```
>>> d.groupby(d.Job.map(lambda x: 'Physician' if 'Physician' in x else x)).sum()
                                       Num
Job                                       
Physical Therapist                      94
Physician                              180
Transportation Security Officer (TSO)   94
```

The idea is to groupby a marker that is set to "Physician" if the string contains "Physician", otherwise set to the original value.  You could extend this to more partial matches.  However, if you have lots of values you want to collapse in this way, it might be more readable to add another column containing the broad categories (e.g., "Physician") and then group on that.

Comment: After your comment to my solution, your solution has the (lesser) side effect that similar column values would also be grouped.

Comment: @Korem: What do you mean by "similar column values"?

Comment: I probably meant row values. If he has two rows with `Physical Therapist` they will be summed, although the OP asked to sum only rows with `Physician`. Perhaps you should return a sequential number instead of x.

Comment: @Korem: I see.  That is true, although it's not clear from the post whether the OP's data has duplicate values like that, or whether he wants to group them if they do exist.  We'll see if he comments about it.

Comment: @BrenBarn might be faster to value_counts on the field in question then just .str.match I think (though depends on the density of the matches)